# Linq outer join syntax

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following query:

```
var query =
     from modules in _Context.Modules
     join moduleStrings in _Context.ModuleStrings on modules.MID equals moduleStrings.MID
     join strings in _Context.Strings on moduleStrings.SID equals strings.SID
     join stringTexts in _Context.StringTexts on strings.SID equals stringTexts.SID into stringsEmpty
     from stringTexts in stringsEmpty.DefaultIfEmpty()
     join languages in _Context.Languages on stringTexts.LID equals languages.LID
     where modules.MID == MID && LID == languages.LID
     select new GridData6S() 
     { 
         Name = strings.Name,
         Text = stringTexts != null ? stringTexts.Text : ""
     };
```

I want to join it so that I see the empty text if stringTexts is null.

It's probably some small thing, but I have been looking at this for an hour and can't figure it out. This is the closest I got.

Comment: Sorry, I now see you already have DefaultIfEmpty in there.  I wonder if it is because you are then going on to try and join to languages.  Have you tried putting the DefaultIfEmpty on that last join too?

Comment: Yes I was just thinking of something along those lines, I'll try!

Comment: Also you might try not using `stringTexts` for both the `join` and `from` clauses, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Did either of these couple of ideas work, I'd be interested to know?

Comment: I'm afraid not, but I'm probably doing something wrong. But I'm sure I'll figure it out eventually and post the answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are filtering out any language that is not LID=languages.LID so when languages/stringTexts are null this condition will never be true.

Also as the only reason you seem to be joining to the languages table is to get the LID which is also the join condition, you could just skip joining to languages

The same is true for modules.....

This might help and is a little simpler

```
var query = 
  from moduleStrings in _Context.ModuleStrings  
  join strings in _Context.Strings on moduleStrings.SID equals strings.SID 
  join stringTexts1 in _Context.StringTexts.Where(x=>x.LID==LID) on strings.SID equals stringTexts.SID into stringsEmpty 
  from stringTexts in stringsEmpty.DefaultIfEmpty() 
  where moduleStrings.MID == MID 
  select new GridData6S()  
  {  
      Name = strings.Name, 
      Text = stringTexts != null ? stringTexts.Text : "" 
  };
```